# Oscillation velocity of an electron in an electric field greater than c?

Tags: special-relativity, electrons, laser-interaction

In relativistic laser matter interaction it is usually defined a parameter $a_0$ as $$a_0 = \frac{e E}{m_e \omega c},$$ with $E$ the amplitude of the oscillating electric field of frequency $\omega$. The quiver (or oscillation) velocity of the electron in the electric field is $$v_{osc} = \frac{e E}{m_e \omega},$$ so that $$a_0 = v_{osc}/c.$$ The relativistic regime of interaction kicks in when $a_0 \geq 1$. This means $v_{osc} \geq c$: how is this possible? $v_{osc}$ shouldn't be always $< c$?

Comment: I think the point is probably that this number getting larger than 1 is a *signal* that you need to take into account relativistic effects, i.e., that $v_{osc}$ as you've written it is no longer the correct expression for the speed of the oscillator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many formulas derived using Newtonian mechanics will fail when applied in a relativistic setting. The formula for Kinetic energy in terms of velocity is a good example: $\text{Ke}=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$. In a relativistic setting, it has to be modified to $$\text{Ke}=m c^2\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}-1\right)$$

Your quantity does have units of velocity though, and there's nothing wrong with quantities with units of velocity being greater in magnitude than $c$. You just have to keep in mind that it is not necessarily the actual velocity of something moving through spacetime.

### Getting an actual relativistic velocity

If we wanted to find that quantity, then I would do the following. The most natural quantity to make with units of momentum is:

$$p_{c} = \frac{e E}{\omega}$$

where I write "c" to stand for "characteristic." Then, relativistic momentum is defined as $p=mv/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$, so we can solve this for $v$ to get: $v=cp/\sqrt{(mc)^2+p^2}$. To make this look more like the Newtonian case, I can write this as $$v=\frac{p}{m}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+p^2/(mc)^2}}$$ If I plug in the mass of the electron and the characteristic momentum on the right, I'll get what I could call the characteristic velocity on the left:

$$v_c=\frac{e E}{m_e \omega}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{e E}{\omega m_e c}\right)^2}}=v_{osc}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(v_{osc}/c)^2}}$$

You can convince yourself that this will always be slower than the speed of light $c$!